# Upload file with Backend Form without update to database using Symfony?

Tags: php, file, symfony1, upload

I writing a function in my form that require user to upload a file, but doesn't necessary have to save it filename in to my database as the program can automatic detect the file.

I try to use this piece of code:

```
$this->setWidget('filename', new sfWidgetFormInputFile());
```

But this required to have a column in database for saving file.

Is there anyway to not use database but include a upload form in symfony 1.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a column in your database, but you need a validator in order to complete your form, sfValidatorFile for exemple.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried to override your updateFilenameColumn method in order to return nothing?